# is there a way to get a list of all the possible 'algorithm/mode/padding' strings for Cipher.getInstance?

Tags: java, security, bouncycastle

I've added BouncyCastle as a provider:

```
java.security.Security.addProvider(
    org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider())
```

Now I want to check out the list of ciphers that are available for `getInstance` - for example:

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC")
```

Is there a way to see list all the different types of crypto algorithms that are avaliable?

Comment: Read the documentation but it can be really hard to find that information, especially the defaults. If there is no documentation don't use that library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through available Security.providers and filter the Services by type. For example:

```
for (Provider provider: Security.getProviders()) {
    System.out.println(provider.getName());
    for (Provider.Service s: provider.getServices()){
        if (s.getType().equals("Cipher"))
            System.out.println("\t"+s.getType()+" "+ s.getAlgorithm());
    }
}
```